# Zipkin UI displaying error message 'ERROR: cannot load service names: No message available'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, zipkin

Trying to create zipkin server with the dependencies added in gradle as below,

```
compile ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin")
compile ("org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit")
compile('io.zipkin.java:zipkin-autoconfigure-ui')
```

Also,

i have added properties in both application.properties and bootstrap.properties files like,

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8085
```

**bootstrap.properties**

```
spring.application.name=zipkin-server
```

Once i start the server and load the UI page i am getting error in UI as,
[image]

Comment: maybe forget @EnableZipkinServer annotation

Comment: did u find the solution? I am having same  issue

Comment: If its spring boot 2.0,downgrade to 1.5.11 because manual creation of zipkin Server is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Hello seeing your screenshot maybe you are using a spring boot 2.x version, I had the same problem with spring boot 2.0.3 with Finchley.RELEASE.

I found that Zipkin custom Server are not any more supported and deprecated for this reason it is not possible to use @EnableZipkinServer in Spring Cloud code and you have the ui but not the server side configured, api endpoint and so on.

form the Zipkin base code:

```
/**
 * @deprecated Custom servers are possible, but not supported by the community. Please use our
 * <a href="https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin#quick-start">default server build</a> first. If you
 * find something missing, please <a href="https://gitter.im/openzipkin/zipkin">gitter</a> us about
 * it before making a custom server.
 *
 * <p>If you decide to make a custom server, you accept responsibility for troubleshooting your
 * build or configuration problems, even if such problems are a reaction to a change made by the
 * OpenZipkin maintainers. In other words, custom servers are possible, but not supported.
 */
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Import(InternalZipkinConfiguration.class)
@Deprecated
public @interface EnableZipkinServer {

}
```

the code is available on [official repo of Zipkin](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/zipkin-server/src/main/java/zipkin/server/EnableZipkinServer.java)
I solve the my problem using the official docker image with a compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15671:15671
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - messaging

  zipkin-server:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    ports:
      - 9065:9411
    environment:
      - zipkin.collector.rabbitmq.uri=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
    networks:
      - messaging

networks:
  messaging:
    driver: bridge
```

How you can see i use the streaming version. it for me work

I hope that is can help you

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
          <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
          <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
```